# .htaccess com subpasta diferente da root

Tags: laravel-4, htaccess

Estava trabalhando com essa estrutura e com esse htaccess:

**estrutura**

```
config/
logs/
www/
    app/
    bootstrap/
    public/
        packages/
        .htaccess
        index.php
        ...
    vendor/
    .htaccess
    ...
```

**htaccess**

```htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Porém peguei uma hospedagem compartilhada em que eu não posso alterar a root, e acabei deixando a estrutura essa forma:

```
config/
logs/
www/
    folder/
        app/
        bootstrap/
        public/
            packages/
            .htaccess
            index.php
            ...
        vendor/
        ...
        .htaccess
```

No htaccess eu deixei o mesmo e também fiz varias alterações, mas nenhuma deu certo. Como eu faria nesse caso ? A pagina fica inteira branca, sem exibir nenhum erro nem nada.

**UPDATE:**
o meu **.htaccess** dentro da pasta **public**, esta dessa forma:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Caso 1: Instalando o Laravel em uma subpasta (Link Simbólico)

Seguindo a sua estrutura, tudo que precisa fazer é criar um link simbólico em `www/folder/index.php` apontando para `www/folder/public/index.php`.

Para fazer isso você pode: entrar na pasta `www/folder` e rodar os comandos:

> ln -s public/index.php index.php
>
> ln -s public/.htaccess .htaccess

E outro link simbólico, em `www/folder/.htaccess` apontando para `www/folder/public/.htacess`.

---

#### Caso 2: Instalando o Laravel em uma subpasta (.htaccess)

Adicone a pasta www/folder o seguinte arquivo `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Após esse mudança, o Laravel não irá mais reconheçer as rotas da mesma forma, pos ele quebra a url em segmentos e existe um segmento adicional chamado 'folder' (nome da sua pasta)

então, as rotas devem seguir o modelo:

```php
Route::get('/folder', function()
{
    return "site.com/folder";
});

Route::get('/folder/login', function()
{
    return "site.com/folder/login";
});
```

---

#### Caso 3: Renomeando a pasta public para www

Você não precisa e não deve hospedar sua aplicação abaixo da pasta pública, por questões de segurança. Se sua pasta pública se chama `www`, o que você deve fazer é:

1. Colocar o conteúdo da pasta `public` dentro de `www`.
2. Alterar a entrada `public` em `bootstrap/paths.php`.

Troque:

```php
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',
```

Por:

```php
'public' => __DIR__.'/../www',
```

Comment: a minha www é a root, e da forma como você falou funciona normalmente, mas no caso desse cliente eu vou precisar inserir a pasta 'folder' após a root e ai sim o conteudo do laravel dentro da 'folder'.

Comment: show @hernandes, funcionou de certa forma. Desculpe mas eu esqueci de especificar, no endereço http://dominio.com.br/folder funcionou perfeitamente exatamente da forma como me passou, mas no caso eu iria utilizar um subdominio que seria http://folder.dominio.com.br. Retirei do arquivo .htaccess a linha RewriteBase /folder e passou a funcionar, mas não esta reconhecendo minhas folhas de estilo, imagens, etc.

Comment: @tiaguinhow qual método da resposta acima você usou? me informe pra que eu posso montar a resposta adequada ao seu problema

Comment: @hernandes usei seu .htaccess e deixei o path como 'public' => __DIR__.'/../public' pois se eu coloco public_html (o que de fato é o da hospedagem) ele não reconhece. A estrutura do site carregou normalmente, o problema esta nos arquivos adicionais.

Comment: @hernandes, flavio me deu uma dica para adicionar a pasta public em todos os assets (asset('public/assets...')) e funcionou. Existe uma maneira de mudar o caminho do asset globalmente ? e do pacote Basset ?

Comment: @tiaguinhow você pode colocar sua pasta assets antes da public. já que ela não é a pasta inicial mais

Comment: desculpa @hernandes, mas como eu faço isso ? E com o Basset há como configurar o diretório padrão também ?

Comment: @tiaguinhow sua hospedagem é cPanel / Plesk ou similar?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12597/discussion-between-tiaguinhow-and-hernandes)

Comment: Em conversa com @hernandes, resolvemos trocar a hospedagem para um que tenha suporte completo ao Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Baseado nas informações que você passou, certamente é a **versão do PHP**:

### Documentação do Laravel 4

> The Laravel framework has a few system requirements:
>
> **PHP >= 5.3.7**
>   MCrypt PHP Extension

[Referência - Laravel 4 Doc](http://laravel.com/docs/installation)

Caso não for isso, tente a solução abaixo, *relacionada ao .htaccess e aos diretórios da hospedagem*.

---

### Laravel 4 em hospedagens compartilhadas

#### Pastas necessárias

Criei as seguintes pastas dentro de `www` (ou `htdocs` / `public_html` - em algumas hospedagens):

```
`www/NOME_DO_PROJETO`
`www/NOME_DO_PROJETO/public`
```

#### Vincular o domínio do projeto

No momento de inserir o domínio do cliente na hospedagem, referencie ele a pasta que criou, porém dentro da sub-pasta `public`, neste caso: `www/NOME_DO_PROJETO/public`.

#### Pronto!

Quando for enviar os arquivos para o servidor, seja pelo FTP, Git ou SVN, coloque-os na pasta `www/NOME_DO_PROJETO`, e dê as devidas permissões em `public` e `storage`.

Com isso, tudo deverá funcionar claramente.

#### Espero que ajude.

*Obs.: não há necessidade de alterar .htaccess, path.php, start.php, etc*

Comment: Obrigado @patrick-maciel, fiz dessa forma mas aconteceu o mesmo problema, a tela fica toda branca e não apresenta nenhuma mensagem, nem nada no código fonte

Comment: @tiaguinhow Estranho. Em branco não era pra ficar. Se seus arquivos estão intactos (htaccess/path/start/etc), com os mesmos paths, era pra funcionar.

Comment: estão intactos sim, a unica coisa que reparei, é que a versão do PHP da hospedagem é 5.3.14, estou vendo para atualizar pra pelo menos 5.3.7 que parece ser a versão compatível com o L4. Vamos ver se isso resolve.

Comment: @tiaguinhow Esta ai o problema então. Vou atualizar a minha resposta.

Comment: opa, agora que atualizei a versão do PHP tivemos uma evolução. Tive que mudar no arquivo bootstrap/path.php para

require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';

agora estou recebendo o seguinte erro de rota:
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

/home/u512270631/public_html/intranetv4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php

sera que ainda preciso alterar/atualizar mais alguma coisa ? Obrigado

Comment: @tiaguinhow Faça um teste básico na sua rota principal, como por exemplo: https://gist.github.com/8479939. Assim você já consegue saber se é um problema no Laravel 4 + servidor, ou apenas com suas rotas.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12538/discussion-between-patrick-maciel-and-tiaguinhow)

Comment: adicione o "public" ao path dos Assets, pois você teve que alterar o caminho do index.php

Comment: Flavio, isso daria certo mas em conversa com o hernandes, isso iria conflitar em mais coisas. Resolvi trocar a hospedagem para um que tenha suporte completo ao Laravel. Obrigado Patrick e Flavio, ambas as ajudas foram de bom proveito.